# The privileges need for a user to alter an audit polity?

Tags: oracle, privileges, audit

I have created a audit policy "select_action_on_tables" by user_a.

```
create audit policy select_action_on_tables
actions select on user_a.test_table1;
```

And i grant "audit_admin" to user_b.

```
grant audit_admin to user_b;
```

but user_b unable to alter the "select_action_on_tables" with ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error.

```
alter audit policy select_action_on_tables add actions select on user_a.test_table2;
```

Do i miss any privileges need for user_b to alter an audit polity? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`AUDIT_ADMIN` is a role, and roles are not activated by default. You either need to alter the user to make the role active by default, or alter the session to activate the role:

```
alter user user_b default role audit_admin [, role1, role2, ...];

alter user user_b default role all;

alter session set role audit_admin;
```

See documentation here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-USER.html#GUID-9FCD038D-8193-4241-85CD-2F4723B27D44
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SET-ROLE.html#GUID-863F9B6F-82B4-4C49-8E3A-3BA33AE79CAB

Also note that a role cannot be activated in existing sessions when first assigned. The designated user must start a new session in order to inherit the new privileges.